# Python: Can't open 'filename' :[Errno 2] no such file or directory

Tags: windows, python

If I type python in windows cmd then it runs python fine, however I can't run any .py files in python. The files work with IDLE. I have set environment variables (to my knowledge, correctly). The files also don't run when I double click them nor if I say open with python. The script also run when I do ctrl + b in Sublime Text 2.

I've looked online for 2 days and can't fix it... maybe I am dumb.
Please help!
[Dragging fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3pek.png) Tried to drag files into the python terminal
[runs in sublime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqBYB.png) Code runs in sublime
[changed file names to run in python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVLIw.png) Tried different names
[Python works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZzww.png) Python works if I type python into windows cmd so path must work.
[listed in dir but doesn't detect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZycPg.png) shows the file is there, but the error is that it doesn't exist

Comment: Can you [edit in](https://superuser.com/posts/1435115/edit) a screenshot or copy/paste of the full text of what you are attempting to do through `CMD`? I think you might be misunderstanding how to run python scripts, but your question is lacking clear details on what you have actually tried.

Comment: Can you provide the directory files screenshot and code of your script... I think you make a python file with the name of the module... Mistakenly...

Comment: Super weird, but I get different errors now and I didn't change anything from earlier. Anyway, I added screenshots of different ways I attempted to run the file in python. I might have forgotten some other ways I tried earlier.

Comment: So no one knows what's wrong? :( 

I've been using IDLE in the meantime. On my other computer I managed to have the program run if I opened the windows cmd and typed hello.py, but if I type python hello,py I got an error. Why would it work in the windows cmd but not in the python one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. I found it here:
https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/win/#install3-windows

After I followed this guide installing chocolatey and then others it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I can see here is most likely caused because you have whitespace in the script's name.

So the command line parses the name of the script up to the first word and thinks it is just `Hello`.

Try those two following things:

```
python "Hello World.py"
```

or

```
python Hello\ World.py
```

The quotes should "tell" the cmd that it is a single argument hence all of it is the name. Even if that doesn't work, the backslash just escapes the whitespace and that should work.

And another thing you could do is just rename the script to something like `Hello_World.py` - without any special symbols or whitespace.

Comment: Thank you for trying, but I get the same error. If I type the path in the python console, itself, then I get the truncated error
\n
C:\Users\xvanz>python "Hello world.py"
C:\Users\xvanz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe: can't open file 'Hello world.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory \n
\n
C:\Users\xvanz>python Hello\ world.py
C:\Users\xvanz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe: can't open file 'Hello\': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: I should also add that I even renamed the file to contain no spaces and tried to run it that way. Same error.